# page is blank when connection to database is included

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have one problem that need all of you to help. I don't know what wrong with it. I created connection to database, it worked. But when i include that connection to other pages, the page is blank, nothing appeared.

**My connection**

*dbconfig.php*

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sample');
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $connection);
?>
```

**Include connection**

```
<?php
include("config/dbconfig.php");
//something that will work from here
?>
```

Do you know why when i include connection to database, that page is display nothing (blank page)?

Thank in advance!

Comment: *"Do you know why when i include connection to database, that page is display nothing (blank page)?"* - Um... you're querying nothing perhaps? You're only "connecting", that's it. You're showing nothing else but `//something that will work from here`

Comment: yes, i select something from database. but nothing happen even normal html tag.

Comment: So, show it then. I failed at mind-reading classes. `$it="query_code";`

Answer (score 1):

Without a better description of what you are trying to do it is most likely not displaying anything because it is connecting successfully.

If the connection  fails you will see an error but otherwise you will see nothing unless you explicitly print it

**otherwise perhaps your include path is incorrect.**

Also, the `mysql` extension is deprecated. Please use the `mysqli` extension instead. the API is almost identical in most of the common functions and it is greatly improved.

Also Also: I would consider leaving the closing tags `?>` off your PHP scripts, you are asking for whitespace errors

Comment: I should have made [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208170/page-is-blank-when-connection-to-database-is-included#comment30132349_20208170) as an answer; what was I thinking?

Comment: heh. we must have been tyhping simultaneously

Comment: in face, everything such as query work fine. but it just when i include that connection, my whole page is blank. Normally, if connection wrong, other default text will show.

Comment: like @Fred-ii- and I have said, assuming your include path is correct, I can offer you not advice without seeing your code to analyse the problem

Comment: @leemo Good luck with the OP, am moving on... (This one stands at being a can of worms). Thanks for the mention btw, cheers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm with ya. Some enterprising answerer may resurrect this at a later date